# bootstrap.min.js IE8 Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and newer version of IE.  However this is for Govt Contract and they are stuck with IE8.

I'm getting error

> Object doesn't support property or method 'on' File: bootstrap.min.js, Line: 6, Column: 1434

I have already tried including *html5shiv.js* and *respond.min.js*, and all my style sheets are local.  My `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` does not display at all in IE8 but works fine in everything else.

I have also added meta tags below

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

this is for an asp.net application..

Comment: What version of bootstrap?  What version of jQuery?

Comment: bootstrap v3.1.1 jQuery -1.4.2

Comment: What about jQuery?  Which version?  If you need to support IE8, you need to use the 1.x series (*not* the 2.x series).

Comment: Bootstrap 3.1.1 doesn't work with jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: its jQuery version 1.4.2 Rocket

Comment: In order to use Bootstrap 3.1.1, you need at least jQuery 1.9 (see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/bower.json)

Comment: k that's what I was thinking maybe a version compatibility issue

Comment: Thanks Rocket you rock.. going to have to see if the powers that be will let me upgrade to 1.9

Comment: If you're gonna upgrade, I'd suggest going all the way to the latest (1.11.0).  This might also come in handy: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/  Also see: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`.on` was added in 1.7](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

And just so you know, the IE-compatible jQuery is already v1.11. Why in the world are you using v1.4?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was as Rocket Hazmat Answered

In order to use Bootstrap 3.1.1, you need at least jQuery 1.9 (see github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/bower.json) –  Rocket Hazmat